# How much of a performance hit does eval() cause in Drools?

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I am new to drools. I was wondering if eval causes an appreciable decrease in evaluation times? There are certain situations in my current project where I have to to use eval. Is the performance difference worth fretting over? Any alternatives?

I know the question might seem a bit open ended, but just wondering out loud. In case there is a lack of clarity or lack of info, do let me know

Your friendly neighborhood coder,

Avinash

Comment: this is very hard to answer. the best thing would be for you to do a PoC and see for yourself

Comment: Gonna do that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst problem is that `eval` is opaque to Drools and so must be re-evaluated every time. The impact this can have on performance may range from negligible to huge, however.

Using `eval` is first and foremost a code smell in Drools and an indication that the solution should be rethought. In the final analysis it is almost never truly necessary, and if it is necessary, then the whole Drools system may be a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: So what's an alternative to call an external function. e.g consider `Car($cost: cost)` and `eval(isMoreThan10K($cost))`. Car object will have a cost but it's not the responsibility of car to know if cost is `>` 10K. How do we fix this?

Comment: I haven't worked with drools for 5 years now, but from what I remember, the solution is caching: add the fact about the cost to the knowledge. Create a new class to hold it if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

instead of using eval it is possible to evaluate using Boolean wrapper class

// eval(value == "India")

Boolean(booleanValue == true) from value == "India"